# Oakley group 2 prime number contains pi, an irrational number

Tags: cryptography, primes, public-key-encryption, number-theory, diffie-hellman

The function for Oakley group 2, p = 2^1024 - 2^960 - 1 + 2^64 * ⌊2^894 * π + 129093⌋, produces a prime number.  It contains pi, an irrational number.  How can an equation containing an irrational number produce a rational product?

I looked on the internet and could not find an answer.  I learned in my mathematical structures class that the product of a rational and irrational number is irrational so this makes me wonder how pi is used to produce a prime.

Comment: Look at the section with pi: "⌊2^894 * π + 129093⌋" Those ⌊...⌋ brackets are the floor function, which rounds a number down to the next lowest integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rossum already answered your question in the comments, but I'm going to elaborate a bit more on the structure of this prime.

As Rossum says, the `⌊⌋` in the `⌊2^894 * π + 129093⌋` portion denote the mathematical floor function, yielding the largest integer less than or equal to the argument. The `2^1024 - 2^960` produces a number where the first 64 bits are `1`s. Multiplying the `⌊2^894 * π + 129093⌋` by `2^64` and subtracting `1` produces a number where the last 64 bits are `1`s.  Combining these, we have a number where the first and last 64 bits are ones, since there will be no carrying in the addition of the two.

Within the `⌊2^894 * π + 129093⌋`, pi is multiplied by `2^894` to extract `896` bits `(1024-64-64)` bits of pi. The `+ 129093` is just an offset to make the overall result prime.

Comment: And for the reason for this structure, see [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2412#page-45) (although it misstates mathematical terminology; if P=2Q+1 with P,Q both prime P is 'safe' and Q is Sophie-Germain)